# I'am trying to scroll a div container with this JavaScript line, but it doesn't work. Why?

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
 1. div.addEventListener(scroll, function(){
 2.       window.scrollBy(50, 0);
 3. });
```

But it does not scroll. What is the reason of this?

Comment: Please edit your question per https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . As for your question: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollBy

Answer (score 0):

You want a scroll on a `div` to trigger a `window` scroll. This is how you can do it:

```
div.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    window.scrollBy(50, 0);
});
```

Comment: I want a div with position:fexed to scroll on the window scrolling

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue with your code is that `window.scrollBy` arguments is horizontal, then vertical.

To scroll the page down by 50 pixels, you need `window.scrollBy( 0, 50 )`.

Comment: It was explicitly